# Переносное значение глагола «готовить»

Tags: значение-слов, глаголы

Употреблен ли глагол "готовить" где-то в переносном значении (метафора, метонимия, функциональный перенос)?

1. Новый станок готовят к пуску.
2. Надо готовить материалы к докладу.
3. Торжественную встречу следует тщательно готовить.
4. Наша бабушка хорошо готовит.

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Ожегова:
[**готовить**](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Gotovit-6058.html), -влю, -вишь; несов.
**1.** *кого-что*. Делать годным, готовым для чего-нибудь (для использования, для осуществления чего-нибудь, для работы). ***Готовить станок к пуску.*** Готовить больного к операции. Готовить молодых специалистов. Институт готовит учителей. [= первое предложение]
**2.** *что*. Работать над освоением, выполнением чего-нибудь. ***Готовить материалы к докладу.*** Готовить уроки. Готовить роль. [= второе предложение]
**3.** *что*. Собираться сделать что-нибудь, замышлять устроить что-нибудь. ***Готовить торжественную встречу гостям.*** [= третье предложение]
**4.** Приготовлять пищу, стряпать. *Умеет готовить. **В нашей столовой хорошо готовят.*** [= четвертое предложение]

*Употреблен ли глагол "готовить" где-то в переносном значении?* **Нет.**

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах глагол употреблён в своём **прямом** значении (*приводить в состояние готовности к чему-либо*). При этом в первых двух примерах в явном виде указано, *к чему* именно готовится названное, в третьем примере "*то, к чему*" опущено (подразумевается "*к проведению*"), а в четвёртом примере опущено "*что*" (еду) и *"к чему"* готовить (*к употреблению* в пищу) - устойчивое сокращённое выражение, узкий смысл которого (готовить = стряпать) выявляется контекстом.